# X509Chain is not building the full chain during RemoteCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: c#, security, ssl, certificate

My Windows service is trying to connect to a website that is signed by the certificate C. C is signed by Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4 (Intermediate CA) and Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4 is signed by VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 (Root CA).

Note: My windows service is running under the privilege of Network Service.

In the client machine where the windows service is installed , I am trying to validate the server certificate. In my certificate store of the local machine I have the VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 (Root CA) in the trusted root CA , but I do not have the intermediate CA in the trusted intermediate root.

Now in the callback of RemoteCertificateValidationCallback , the X509Chain is containing only 1 element i.e certificate C.

**Can anyone explain the reason why and what needs to be done so that the full chain is built.**

Additional Observations:
Note : When I ran the windows service as a user X who is in the administrator group on the same machine. The full chain was built and the intermediate certificate was installed in the User's Store trusted intermediate certificates.

Note: When I elevated the NETWORK SERVICE as part of the administrator group , the problem was still there and the full chain is not built.

Note : When I ran the windows service as Local system account and the logged in user is part of the administrator group on the same machine.the problem was still there and the full chain is not built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why the full chain was not built is due to a missing proxy configuration! in a windows machine there are 3 classes of applications and the way you configure proxies for them are different. The 3 classes are

1. Applications that have their own proxy settings which uses winsock. These applications has to manage proxy settings themselves.
2. Applications using the WinINET library - WinINET is the core of Internet Explorer and it can also be used by other applications. Any applications that use this library would use the proxy settings provided in Internet Explorer.
3. Applications using the WinHTTP library - Non Interactive applications mainly use WinHTTP library. The proxy settings provided in Internet explorer will not be used by WinHTTP library.

The Windows service in the question belongs to the 3rd category and it was not using the Proxy settings of Internet Exploror. So the Chain building engine of .net was not able to download the intermediate CA! Once we configured the Proxy Server settings of Win HTTP it worked!

Also , the follwing links has explaination on how the certificate chain is built. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700843.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619754(v=ws.10).aspx

The interesting part of chain building is that it also looks into the disk and memory caches before using the AIA (Authority Information Access) , thus even if you put wireshark you will not find a trace of the http call to the AIA url . This is because it is there in the memory cache and to see the AIA call one needs to either invalidate the cache settings or delete them.

Location:

Per User ==>
C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\ Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache

For Network Service in my case ==>
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache